# codeigniter unit testing queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing

I'm new to codeIgniter and unit test, and i want to test this query that return a multidimentionnal array

```
    public function get_ficheFrais($selected_visiteur_np) {

    $query = $this->db->select('ff.mois')
            ->from('fichefrais ff')
            ->join('utilisateur u', 'u.id = ff.idVisiteur', 'inner')
            ->where('ff.idVisiteur', $selected_visiteur_np)
            ->where('ff.idEtat', 'VA')
            ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

this is the var_dump of the query:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
object(stdClass)[42]
  public 'mois' => string '201211' (length=6)
```

but i can't find out how to write it in the test function. i've tried this:

```
    $this->visiteur_model->get_ficheFrais('a131');
    $data['ficheFrais'] = $this->visiteur_model->get_ficheFrais('a55');

    $this->unit->run($data['ficheFrais'], (array ('mois'=>'201211')), "testing get_ficheFrais function");
    $this->load->view('visiteur/v_tests');
```

can anyone help or has a better solution on how to test queries that return arrays?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Are you trying to get single variables to test?

Comment: i'm trying to test that the result of the query (the one in the var_dump) is the same that the one one i put as expected in the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think were you are going wrong is you are expecting your `get_ficheFrais` function to return an array but its actually returning an object.  If you want it to return an array you want to change it from

```
return $query->result();
```

to

```
return $query->result_array();
```

So bearing in mind it returns an object at the moment you want to change your unit test to

```
$this->unit->run($data['ficheFrais']->mois, 201211, "testing get_ficheFrais function");
```

Comment: Allright Thanks! it works now: $this->unit->run($data['ficheFrais'][0]->mois, '201211', "testing get_ficheFrais function"